# How to value initialize derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Currently I am using `std::initializer_list<std::vector<double>>` to initialize my matrix class.

```
class matrix{
public:
    matrix(std::initializer_list<std::vector<double>> list: row(list.size(),
                               col((*list.begin()).size()), matrix(list){}

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double> matrix; // I am planning to use single contiguous memory in future
};
```

This allows me to value initialize matrix

`matrix mat = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};`

Now I use matrix to create vector (mathematical)

```
class Vector: public Matrix{
    Vector(std::initializer_list<double> list):Matrix(list){}
    // Vector(std::initializer_list<std::vector<double>> list):Matrix(list){}

};
```

What I wanted to do for Vector was

`Vector vec = {1,2,3};`

but since I can't pass `std::initializer_list<double>` to base I am stuck with

`Vector vec = {{1,2,3}};` which I don't want.

Is there any other way to handle this situation (by dropping the initializer_list and using something completely different) or should I stick with initializer_list?

I think the intializer_list does the initialization in run time, I read it from [here](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/the-cost-of-stdinitializer_list/). Is there a way where I could do the initialization in compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your code, so that at least it compiles. Hope it helps:

```
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<vector<double>> _list):
            row(_list.size()),  col((*_list.begin()).size()), m_matrix(_list){}

private:
    size_t row, col;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> m_matrix; // I am planning to use single contiguous memory in future
};

class MyVector: public Matrix{
public:
    MyVector(std::initializer_list<double> _list): Matrix({_list}) {}
};
```

As a side not, its not good idea to use vector or list as veriable names, as these are container names in C++ STL.

Comment: So I tried this and it works! I know this is run time initialization .. can you point to any resource which would do this initialization in compile time some how? I am not sure if compile time initialization is possible this way but was just curious

Comment: @pokche Not sure. Maybe something with templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `initializer_list<initializer_list<double>>` to the parent `matrix` class:

```
Vector(std::initializer_list<double> list):matrix({list}){}
```